# Exporting Holdout shader to gLTF/glb

Tags: eevee-render-engine, gltf

I tried exporting a plane with the holdout shader as it's material but it appears solid in the .glb file. Any ideas on how I might get the holdout shader effect in a .glb file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Holdout shaders do not export from Blender to any format I'm aware of, unfortunately. Isn't the same thing of course, but you can export Principled BSDF Alpha Blend transparency and transmission. You can also export a shadeless material, like a Background node.

Comment: I will try that and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: I tried what you said but I didn't get the effect I wanted. I was wondering of there was a way to have a invisible plane that also acts as an occluder in my glb file.